# load a csv file from a particular point onwards

Tags: sql, csv, file-upload

I have the below code to read a particular csv file, my problem is that the csv file contains two sets of data, one underneath the other, with different headers.

The starting point of the second data set can vary daily. So I need something that lets me find the row in the CSV where the second dataset begins (it will always start with the number '302') and load the csv from there. The problem i have is that the code below starts from where i need it to start, but it always includes the headers from the first part of the data, which is wrong.

```
USE csvImpersonation
    FILE 'c:\\myfile.TXT'
    SKIP_AT_START 3
RETURN @myfile

@loaddata = SELECT * FROM @mylife
where c1 = '302'
```

The below is a sample of the text file (after the first 3 rows are skipped, which are just full of file settings, dates, etc).

[image]

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: it is a purpose-built company tech, but it uses simple SQL with the option of using r or python should you wish.